# Generating Ansible YAML file with Python

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

How can I generate an Ansible YAML playbook using Python3, so it looks like this:

email.yml

```
---
  - name: Send a success email
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - name: send email
        mail:
          host: "smtp.email.com"
          port: 587
          sender: "Notification notification@email.com"
          username: "notification@email.com"
          password: "password"
          to: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
          cc: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
          subject: "Backup complete - test"
          subtype: html
          body: "<h1>The backup of</h1><br> .. is complete."
          secure: starttls
```

I have tried parsing the YAML file in Python and putting it in a script that uses the same format as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import yaml

d=[None, [{'name': 'Send a success email', 
        'hosts': 'localhost', 
        'tasks': [{'name': 'send email', 
        'mail': {'host': 'smtp.email.com', 
        'port': 587, 
        'sender': 'Notification notification@email.com', 
        'username': 'notification@email.com', 
        'password': 'password', 
        'to': 'Some Email <some.email@university.edu>', 
        'cc': 'Some Email <some.email@university.edu>', 
        'subject': 'Backup complete - test', 
        'subtype': 'html', 
        'body': '<h1>The backup of</h1><br> .. is complete.',
        'secure': 'starttls'}}]}]]

f=open('output.yaml','w')
f.write(yaml.dump(d))
f.close
```

Result of output.yaml:

```
- null
- - hosts: localhost
    name: Send a success email
    tasks:
    - mail:
        body: <h1>The backup of</h1><br> .. is complete.
        cc: Some Email <some.email@university.edu>
        host: smtp.email.com
        password: password
        port: 587
        secure: starttls
        sender: Notification notification@email.com
        subject: Backup complete - test
        subtype: html
        to: Some Email <some.email@university.edu>
        username: notification@email.com
      name: send email
```

Couple of issues here: no double quotes, lines are not in order.

**Solution:**
I was able to solve the issue I was having with ruamel.yaml and round_trip to preserve double quotes much needed for the yaml file i was looking to generate.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inp = """\
- name: "Send a successful email"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: "send email"
    mail:
      hosts: "smtp.email.com"
      port: 587
      sender: "Notification notification@email.com"
      username: "notification@email.com"
      password: "password"
      to: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
      cc: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
      subject: "Backup complete - test"
      subtype: html
      body: "<h1> The backup of </h1><br> .. is complete"
      secure: starttls
"""

yaml = YAML()
code = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(inp, preserve_quotes=True)

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
- name: "Send a successful email"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: "send email"
    mail:
      hosts: "smtp.email.com"
      port: 587
      sender: "Notification notification@email.com"
      username: "notification@email.com"
      password: "password"
      to: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
      cc: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
      subject: "Backup complete - test"
      subtype: html
      body: "<h1> The backup of </h1><br> .. is complete"
      secure: starttls
```

Comment: Take a look at this page. It should answer your question https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: The main problem

Comment: The main problem:
#1 I can't get the script to write lines in order as in original yaml file
#2 I'm unable to add double quotes in yaml file, same way as in original

Comment: Is this question solved already? Is there a reason *why* you want the items ordered and the strings quoted? YAML works with both.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue I was having with ruamel.yaml and round_trip to preserve double quotes much needed for the yaml file i was looking to generate.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inp = """\
- name: "Send a successful email"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: "send email"
    mail:
      hosts: "smtp.email.com"
      port: 587
      sender: "Notification notification@email.com"
      username: "notification@email.com"
      password: "password"
      to: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
      cc: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
      subject: "Backup complete - test"
      subtype: html
      body: "<h1> The backup of </h1><br> .. is complete"
      secure: starttls
"""

yaml = YAML()
code = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(inp, preserve_quotes=True)

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
- name: "Send a successful email"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: "send email"
    mail:
      hosts: "smtp.email.com"
      port: 587
      sender: "Notification notification@email.com"
      username: "notification@email.com"
      password: "password"
      to: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
      cc: "Some Email <some.email@university.edu>"
      subject: "Backup complete - test"
      subtype: html
      body: "<h1> The backup of </h1><br> .. is complete"
      secure: starttls
```